# The asynchronous action method returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

This Code is running fine on my local machine

```
public async Task<ActionResult> teststuff()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var twitter = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.twitter.com");
            Response.Write(twitter);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

However when I upload to the server I Get the error response

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The asynchronous action method 'teststuff' returns a Task, which
>   cannot be executed synchronously.    Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous
>   action method 'teststuff' returns a Task, which cannot be executed
>   synchronously.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method 'teststuff'
>   returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +125
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__10()
>   +120    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +637
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +307
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +688
>   NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeActionWith404Catch(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +54
>   NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +19
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__19() +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

There is something missing on my server but just can't find out what it is any help would be appreciated.

I have tried re-installing .net framework 4.5 on the server but that had no effect. However I did notice on the sever it has both the

Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack and
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack

Not sure if I should remove the 4 one or not?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `/configuration/system.web/compilation@targetFramework` set to `4.5`?

Comment: Yea I just check and the targetFramework is set to 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was odd I just deleted all the files in the website then re published the site and it all work fine.

I think this may have happen because I recently upgraded the site from a MVC3 site to MVC4 and there may have been an odd DLL left from the MVC3 site in the Directory.

Thanks Stephen for you suggestion it gave me the idea of wiping the site clean and re upping it

Answer (score 3):

I had this error after subclassing `ControllerActionInvoker` in order to inject dependencies into MVC attributes using Ninject. This page describes the process of doing this: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/02/10/how-to-use-ninject-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp.net-mvc.aspx

I had some asynchronous methods in my controller, and this error was appearing when these asynchronous methods were called. It turns out that I needed to not subclass `ControllerActionInvoker`, but `System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker`.

After changing the base class, my code was happy and it ran just fine.

Comment: I had the same problem just now on an application using CastleWindsor for DI of Action Filters.

Comment: Omg!! Thanks you so much! This work for me in CastleWindsor too