# Async Action in ASP.net MVC 5 and Entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

i have a problem with async action in mvc

i wrote this code and it compiles successfully

```
public class aminController : Controller
{

    private IPLF.Data.IPLFContext db = new IPLFContext();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        return View(await db.LibOrgs.ToListAsync());
    }

}
```

when i run my website and go to the action , i get this error

[image]

what should i do ????

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/the-asynchronous-action-method-returns-a-task-which-cannot-be-executed-synchron

Comment: thanks for your reply 
i saw all the related post on stackoverflow and did all the things they said but nothing solved my problem 
my target framework is set to 4.5

Comment: I tried something similar with MVC5 and there was no problem. Try stepping thorough and see exactly what line causes the exception

Comment: i deleted all files in bin folder and rebuild the project and it works . 
probably clean not deleted all files in the bin folder . i don't know !! 
tanks anyway for your time ned .

Comment: I would recommend this article http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc Hope it helps