# ASP.NET MVC with Async Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I need to send an asynchronous email from an Async action. I do not understand why the following error is happening, being that I use this same class in other projects and use the same form only without errors, everything quiet.

Error:

> The asynchronous action method 'EsqueciMinhaSenhaAsync' returns a Task, which
>   cannot be executed synchronously.

Action:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EsqueciMinhaSenhaAsync(UsuarioEsqueciMinhaSenhaViewModel vModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var conteudo = "este é o conteudo do email";
                var nomeRemetente = "esse é o nome do remetente";

                if(await EmailService.SendAsync(Language.PasswordRecovery, conteudo, vModel.EmailOuUsername, nomeRemetente))
                {
                    TempData["MensagemRetorno"] = Language.EmailSendedWithSuccess;
                    return View("login");
                }
            }

            TempData["MensagemRetorno"] = Language.ErrorSendingEmail;
            return View("EsqueciMinhaSenha");
        }
```

My Email Service:

```
    public static async Task<bool> SendAsync(string assunto, string conteudo, string destinatario, string nomeDestinatario)
    {
        // Habilitar o envio de e-mail
        var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        if (appSetting != null && appSetting.Count >= 7 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assunto) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(conteudo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinatario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeDestinatario))
        {
            int port = 0;
            bool useSSl = false;

            using (var msg = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(appSetting["EmailFrom"], appSetting["EmailNameFrom"]),
                Body = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(conteudo)
            })
            {
                int.TryParse(appSetting["EmailPort"], out port);
                bool.TryParse(appSetting["EmailUseSSL"], out useSSl);


                msg.ReplyToList.Add(destinatario);
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(destinatario, nomeDestinatario));
                msg.Subject = assunto;
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(appSetting["EmailServer"], port))
                {
                    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(appSetting["EmailUserName"], appSetting["EmailPassword"]);
                    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = useSSl;
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);

                    return await Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(false);
    }
```

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method
>   'esqueciminhasenha' returns a Task, which cannot be executed
>   synchronously.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +119
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +22    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +189
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +521
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +95
>
>   MusiArtist.MVC.Areas.admin.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore() in
>   F:\Backup\BitBucket\negrini.musiartist\src\MusiArtist.MVC\Areas\admin\Controllers\BaseController.cs:29
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +180    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass19.<BeginExecute>b__13() +18    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Action action) +15
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +16
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: replace `await Task.FromResult` with just `true` or `false` in the email service

Comment: @Nkosi same error =/

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/the-asynchronous-action-method-returns-a-task-which-cannot-be-executed-synchron

Comment: @Nkosi 
276/5000
As I said, I have always used this in other projects and I had no problems, I can not change my base controller as this solution says, I have my own controller base that inherits from "Controller", however the "Controller" should work, In my other projects.

Comment: @LuizNegrini replace `await Task.FromResult` with the actual values. Awaiting for an already completed task is pointless. While it may not be the cause of the problem, it's a waste of CPU cycles and makes the code uglier;

Comment: The error complains about your action method itself, not the Email service. Please post your controller code.

Comment: Was the project upgraded from MVC 3 perhaps? [In this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/the-asynchronous-action-method-returns-a-task-which-cannot-be-executed-synchron) the upgrade process left some old dlls. Once they were removed, the application worked without problem

Comment: To verify that the upgrade is the problem try creating a *new* MVC project with just that single controller and action.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have said several times, in another project running the same version is working.

Comment: @LuizNegrini which doesn't mean anything if there are leftover dlls in your production folder. Just try and verify the problem first. Don't assume that MVC 4 *and* the error message *and* every programmer that uses MVC 4 is broken. The only google results for such an error link to issues with leftover files

Comment: @LuizNegrini actually, the fact that this code works in other projects means that it's *NOT* a coding problem. Why don't you try doing a clean deployment? Or at least check the dll versions in the debug folder? You may be using an old NuGet package that added the wrong dependency

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It worked normally ... I created a new project and changed the index of the home controller and it worked normally, it really can be something old running, but I did not update the project for a new version, the project was already created in the same version as this one I created now to test. How do I analyze this problem and check if the dlls are the same? Is there a shortcut?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I've cleaned all debug and obj folders but it does not solve at all.

Comment: @LuizNegrini can you post the full exception, including its call stack? Also, how do you test your code? Do you deploy to IIS or run under the dev web server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will post, but only later, I am not at my place of work. Thank you for the support. Yes it runs in visual studio normally, without deploy some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an override on the "DisableAsyncSupport" method of the Controller and set the getter to false and everything worked perfectly!!!

```
protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
{
    get { return false; }
}
```

I believe that by inheriting from controller (I have my own controller, "ControllerBase") the method must behave differently.