# DI/IoC for .net mvc async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, simple-injector

I'm using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) as the IoC container for my .Net MVC project. Here is how I register the services.

**SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs**

```
 public static void Initialize() {
    var container = new Container();

    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();  
    //container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle(); // replace last line with this for async/await

    InitializeContainer(container);
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}

private static void InitializeContainer(Container container) {
    container.Register<MyDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ICustomerService, CustomerService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    //what does this do by the way?
    //using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope()) {
    //}
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
public interface ICustomerService : IService<Customer> {}

public class CustomerService : BaseService<Customer, MyDbContext>, ICustomerService {
    public CustomerService(IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext> unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) {}
    // do stuff
}

public class CustomerController : Controller {
    private readonly ICustomerService _service;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        var foo = _service.GetById(112); // works
        // do stuff
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<int> Foo() { // error out on calling this method
        var foo = await _service.GetByIdAsync(112); 
        return foo.SomeId;
    }
}
```

My problem is that whenever I used async/await, the ioc failed. Then I looked its [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-execution-context-scope-async-await), it got a different `LifeStyle` for Asynchronous methods. So I changed the `DefaultScopeLifeStyle` to `ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle()`, it errored out

> The ICustomerService is registered as 'Execution Context Scope' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Execution Context Scope.

Do I need to implement a hybrid lifestyle for using asyn/await as well as synchronous methods? Or something is wrong in my design?

**Error detail** (with `WebRequestLifestyle`)

> The asynchronous action method 'foo' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method 'foo' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous action method 'foo' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +119
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +256
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +522
>      NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeActionWith404Catch(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +32
>      NotFoundMvc.ActionInvokerWrapper.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e() +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

**Edit**
I've confirmed it's not a Simple Injector issue, it's really [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/the-asynchronous-action-method-returns-a-task-which-cannot-be-executed-synchron?noredirect=1&lq=1). I've tried to clean the solution, remove the dlls in the bin folder, still no luck with same error. However, I changed the controller to an ApiController, the asyn worked well.

Comment: You state "error out before hit this line" when using the `WebRequestLifestyle`. Can you post the complete exception details (exception type, message and stack trace of the exception and all inner exceptions) that you get?

Comment: @Steven added the full error details.

Comment: Hi Quentin, that was not the error I was looking for. This is the exception you get when you are using the `ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle`. Instead, change the `Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle` to `WebRequestLifestyle` and post the exception related to that change. ps. Instead of posting an image, please post the exception details as text instead. This makes it easier to read, copy and for other search engines to index your question.

Comment: @Steven It's `The asynchronous action method 'foo' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.` I'm adding the details momentarily.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, this problem is not related to Simple Injector and its scoping; if you wrap an execution context scope around a web request (which is something you can do by hooking into the request_start and request_end events), you will be faced by the same problem.

There are several issues about this on Stackoverflow and the rest of the interwebs, that you should take a look at, such as [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/).

Comment: Thank you for the input. So should I use `ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle` instead of `WebRequestLifestyle` when dealing with async methods?

Comment: @Quentin: No, you can keep using the `WebRequestLifestyle` in MVC.